# Vega-lite interactive Bar Chart

Tags: graph, charts, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to make a basic interactive chart where the user can select a country and observe a single measurement based on the height of the bar. However, prior to selecting a country, the chart shows all the bars stacked on top of each other. once a country is selected i achieve the view that i want.

```
{"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  
  
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConorQuah/ConorQuah.github.io/main/Happiness%26liberties_s%26e.csv"
  },

  "title": {
    "text": "Happiness and Liberty",
    "subtitle":"view the happiness of different countries. Notice how the colour of the bar changes!",
    "subtitleFontStyle":"italic",
    "subtitleFontSize":10,
    "anchor": "start"
  },

  "height": 300,
  "width": 300,

  "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "Region"}}],
  
  "selection": {
    "Region": {
      "type": "single",
      "fields": ["Country"],
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "null",
          "Finland",
          "Sweden",
          "New Zealand",
          "United Kingdom",
          "Serbia",
          "Zimbabwe",
          "Afghanistan"
          
        ],
        "name": "Select a country"
      }
    }
  },


  "mark": {"type": "bar", "width":50},

  

  "encoding": {
    
     "color": {
                "field": "Civil liberties",
                "title": "Civil liberties",
                "scale":{"scheme":"redyellowgreen", "domain":[0,60]},
                "type": "quantitative"
                
          },
    
    
    
    "y": {
      "field": "Happiness", 
      "scale": {"domain": [0,10]},
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Happiness"
    }



    
    
      
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConorQuah/ConorQuah.github.io/main/Happiness%26liberties_s%26e.csv"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Happiness and Liberty",
    "subtitle": "view the happiness of different countries. Notice how the colour of the bar changes!",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start"
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "p",
      "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["Country"]},
      "bind": { "name": "Country",
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "Pick a Country",
          "Finland",
          "Sweden",
          "New Zealand",
          "United Kingdom",
          "Serbia",
          "Zimbabwe",
          "Afghanistan"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 300,
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Country ==p_Country"}],
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": 50},
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "Civil liberties",
      "title": "Civil liberties",
      "scale": {"scheme": "redyellowgreen", "domain": [0, 60]},
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Happiness",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]},
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Happiness"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works as desired on vega thank you, however does not appear when transferred to visual studio. It appears to be an issue with the code as other vega chart codes seem compatible. Do you know what might be the problem?